# Chai.js: How to correctly use the `and` getter in a language chain

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chai

**Background**

I would appreciate help with learning how to use the `and` getter as part of a language chain in [Chai](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/). I have tried this code:

```
describe ('', function () {
    it ('', function () {

        expect(myVariable).to.be.a('number').and.not.a(NaN);
        expect(myVariable).to.be.a('number').and.not.to.be.a(NaN);
    }
}
```

but both expressions results in the following error message:

> TypeError: type.toLowerCase is not a function

**Question**

How do I correctly use the `and` getter to test if `myVariable` is a `"number"` and at the same time ensure that it is not a `NaN`?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
expect(myVariable).to.be.a('number').and.not.a.NaN;
```